# How to implement dynamic theme in django app?

Tags: django, styles, multi-tenant

My app is multitenant, with many groups with unique site like group1.myapp.com, group2.myapp.com etc. Requirement is that user should be able to select different theme for a particular group.

I don't seem to come up with good approach to do it. Anyone has done before? Would be really grateful to get some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Basically, I am allowing users to select color and background which are basic theme component and save them in db. Then I make theme from the variables, using LESS CSS which works great. I use NodeJS for LESS to CSS server-side compilation.

Python/Django part of the solution is open sourced on github as [Django dynamic-theme](https://github.com/neokya/dynamic-theme). Go through the code if you want to implement something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't started yet, you can consider using [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) for having switchable css for themes.

For example, here's the [demo site](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/blog/) for Mezzanine which uses switchable themes by saving the theme name in a cookie.

Here's the relevant part in the demo code which handles this:

https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine.jupo.org/blob/master/templates/base.html#L28

Comment: Thanks @tuxcanfly. That looks awesome. Looked at Mezzanine project few months back, was really impressed. 
Now I need to go a bit inside code on how they have implemented it.